# SSH connection failed on GitLab CI/CD

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to set up an environment to

1. develop WordPress theme localy
2. push to GitLab repositly
3. then automatically deploy to staging server.

Currently, i log in to the staging server, make a pull request, and it deploy from GitLab repository.　but i would like to automatize this step so decided to learn to use CI.

this is my gitlab-ci.yml ↓

```
deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy

  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."    
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p $SSH_PORT -v $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "cd /var/www/wp/project_name/wpcontent/themes/theme_name && git checkout main && git pull origin main && exit"

  environment: production
```

and when it run, i get error log like ↓

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.3.0~beta.108.g2b6048b4 (2b6048b4)
  on green-3.saas-linux-small-amd64.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default Jhc_Jxvh, system ID: s_0e6850b2bce1
  feature flags: FF_USE_IMPROVED_URL_MASKING:true, FF_RESOLVE_FULL_TLS_CHAIN:false
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:19
Using Docker executor with image ruby:3.1 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:3.1 ...
Using docker image sha256:################################# for ruby:3.1 with digest ruby@sha256:########################################### ...
Preparing environment
00:05
Running on runner-jhcjxvh-project-45805569-concurrent-0 via runner-jhcjxvh-s-l-s-amd64-1696296011-84e5f577...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/ltech4/project_name/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 0ef72ff4 as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ git remote set-url origin "${CI_REPOSITORY_URL}"
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:03
Using docker image sha256:#################################### for ruby:3.1 with digest ruby@sha256:######################################################## ...
$ echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
This job deploys something from the main branch.
$ ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p $SSH_PORT -v $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "cd /var/www/wp/wp-content/themes/project_name && git checkout main && git pull origin main && exit"
OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2, OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug1: Connecting to ***.***.***.*** [***.***.***.***] port **.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /builds/ltech4/project_name.tmp/STAGE_ID_RSA type 0
debug1: identity file /builds/ltech4/project_name.tmp/STAGE_ID_RSA-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to **.***.***.***:** as '#####'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:###########################
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SELinux support disabled
Warning: Permanently added '[***.***.***.***]:**' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: check_host_key: hostkey not known or explicitly trusted: disabling UpdateHostkeys
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /builds/ltech4/project_name.tmp/STAGE_ID_RSA RSA SHA256:######################################### explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /builds/ltech4/project_name.tmp/STAGE_ID_RSA RSA SHA256:############################################ explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
######@***.***.***,***: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

It seems like it's having a trouble logging in with SSH.
i would appriciate if anyone help me to solve this problem

The problem seemed to be that the ssh key had a passphrase, so I temporarily disabled it but still i got this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you should ssh from within your ci - it feels messy.

There is no reason you can’t install a gitlab self hosted runner on the staging machine (a shell runner will be easiest).

Then just create a job that references that one and does your git commands to get the new theme.

This way you control the flow from gitlab and don’t need to worry about sshing, you can let the runner handle connection to your gitlab repo.

Alternatively if you feel very strong about sshing - the gitlab runner also has an ssh executor which can remotely connect to the staging machine and run the commands, although it would work the same as what I’ve mentioned above just with some extra config and steps.